# vertical subtables not aligning properly

Tags: tables

I have 4 sub tables inside a table environment. The sub tables are too far to the right and the sub caption for the sub tables is also not centered below the sub tables. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

```
\begin{table} [htp]
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}[c]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline Class & Recall & FP & Precision & F-Measure & MCC \\
            \hline normal      &    0.924     &  0.380  &   0.648        &   0.762        &  0.554   \\
            \hline anomaly      & 0.620       &  0.076  &    0.915       &    0.739       &  0.554    \\
            \hline
            Weighted Avg. & 0.751 & 0.207 & 0.800 & 0.749 & 0.554 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{SVM-Linear Performance Metrics \label{tbl:svmlinearaccuracy}}
        \vspace{10mm}           
    \end{subtable}
\quad%  
    \begin{subtable}[c]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline Class & Recall & FP & Precision & F-Measure & MCC \\
            \hline normal      &    0.967     &  0.391  &   0.652        &   0.779        &  0.594   \\
            \hline anomaly      & 0.609       &  0.033  &    0.961       &    0.745       &  0.594    \\
            \hline
            Weighted Avg. & 0.763 & 0.187 & 0.828 & 0.760 & 0.594 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{SVM-Polynomial Performance Metrics \label{tbl:svmpolynomialaccuracy}}
        \vspace{10mm}           
    \end{subtable}
\quad%   
    \begin{subtable}[c]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline Class & Recall & FP & Precision & F-Measure & MCC \\
            \hline normal      &    0.925     &  0.403  &   0.635       &   0.753        &  0.534   \\
            \hline anomaly      & 0.597       &  0.075  &    0.913       &    0.722       &  0.534    \\
            \hline
            Weighted Avg. & 0.738 & 0.216 & 0.793 & 0.735 & 0.534 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{SVM Sigmoid Performance Metrics \label{tbl:svmsigmoidaccuracy}}
        \vspace{10mm}
    \end{subtable}
\quad%  
    \begin{subtable}[c]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline Class & Recall & FP & Precision & F-Measure & MCC \\
            \hline normal      &    0.924     &  0.409  &   0.631       &   0.750        &  0.528   \\
            \hline anomaly      & 0.591       &  0.076  &    0.911       &    0.717       &  0.528    \\
            \hline
            Weighted Avg. & 0.734 & 0.220 & 0.790 & 0.731 & 0.528 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{SVM RBF Performance Metrics \label{tbl:svmrbfaccuracy}}
        \vspace{10mm}
    \end{subtable}  
    \caption{Main Table}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your problem is that your tables are wider than `.5\textwidth`. Increase that and you're fine. Try for example `\textwidth`, because you have the tables stacked vertically (you should forget to get two in a line with your `\quad`).

Comment: @TeXnician trying with just \textwidth worked. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table includes subtables which are too broad to fit two on one line. And they are too broad for the `.5\textwidth`. Hence you should increase that subtable width to `\textwidth` and remove the `\quad` macros (replace them with `\\`).

Then you should have the right formatting. Actually they are formatted correctly, because the caption is centered across the `.5\textwidth`.